# What does this regular expression mean. Is it enough to check http or https hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone advise? And how does the replace all method works?

```
message = message.replaceAll("(?:https?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+",
"<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be taken this each step at a time to understand:

```
(?:https?|http?)
```

`|`  -> means OR so it means matches either https or http

`?`  -> (only here) means optional elements, "s" from https is optional or "p" from http is optional too. What you probably meant is to do : "`(https)?|(http)?`", make each optional. But this is still wrong, because you then could match a String like this one: "`://someLink`" - which does not make sense.

I suppose you want to match https OR http, thus your regex here needs to changed to :

```
 https? (to make only the s optinal)
```

`?:` -> it defines a non-capturing group (it means it will be matched but not present in the output - not captured in the result), this is something related to regex groups.

`()` -> mean that this is a group 
    and as matter of fact this is the second group (the first is the whole match itself)

This regex "`://[\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+`" has been explained above pretty good I think.

Here is the "magic" that happens here: "`$0`", this is called a backreference to a matching group. So inside your message String, the result that you have matched with the regex:

```
(?:https?|http?)://[\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+
```

will be replaced with this:

```
"<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>"
```

where `$0` is actually the thing that was found with the first regex.

Here is an example actually:

```
// I've simplified: \\w+ any number of characters
String regex = "https?://\\w+";
String input = "http://value1 ; https://value2";
input = input.replaceAll(regex, "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a> ");

// this will output : 
// <a href='http://value1' target='_blank'>http://value1</a>  ; <a href='https://value2' target='_blank'>https://value2</a>
System.out.println(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test you regexps here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ It also has a couple of user-contributed regexps you can try. I tried your regexp and did not get any match. But I played around with it a bit and I think you meant: `(?:https?)://[\w/%.\-?&=!#]+` and also, I suggest you use

```
message = message.replaceAll(/(?:https?):\/\/[\w\/%.\-?&=!#]+/g,
"<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>");
```

hope I helped.

edit:
I did not find any documentation on the `replaceAll` method, so I suggest you use the replace method. You can try it here: http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Also, you do not have any capturing groups (marked with `(` and `)`)  so the $0 will not work in your replace. So it should be

```
message = message.replaceAll(/((?:https?):\/\/[\w\/%.\-?&=!#]+)/g,
"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
```

Note that I made the whole regexp a capturing group and replaced $0 with $1. You can also have multiple capturing groups ex. `(https?):\/\/([\w\/%.\-?&=!#]+)` and here $1 will be your protocol (http or https) and $2 will be the rest of the link ex. `something.com?i=1`

Answer (score 1):

It says, Match with a string or a part of string that

1. has `http`, or `https`
2. followed by `://`
3. followed by one or more any of word character`[a-zA-Z0-9]`, `/`, `%`, `.` , `-`, `?`, `&`, `=`, `!` or `#`

replace it with `<a href='MATCHED_STRING' target='_blank'>MATCHED_STRING</a>`

Now, will it match will all URL? No. Mostly, but not all. It will match `my name is boxiehttp://random`, Ideally you would want to put a word boundary liek `\\b`

[removed misleading comments]

Comment: In no regex language that I know of is a period inside a character class special and in need of being escaped.

Comment: And usually `]` and `[` (under certain circumstances).

Answer (score 1):

[`replaceAll`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) is a `String` class method and matches a `Regex` and replace it with a parameterized string. Parameters (like `$0`) are the matches index.

Your `regex` is supposed to matches all urls and convert them to anchor tags but I suggest a few improvements:

- In your regex, you're using `(?:https?|http?)`. `(?:SOMETHING)` matches a non-capturing group and `?` makes the preceding character optional (so it matches `http` and `htt`.)

  You would use `https?` instead.
- It's generally not necessary to escape characters (like `-` or `&`) in regex classes.

---

so the [regex](http://regexr.com?2vtlo) would be:

```
.replaceAll("https?://[\\w/%.-?&=!#]+", "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know java regex expression. 
but I try to explain the regex based on javascript.

`(?:https?|http?)` : http or https, okay if not exist. (?:...) means no memory assign. just pass.

`://` : this is the same character with "://"

`[\\w/%.\\-?&=!#]+` : this is regex class, 
    `\\w` : all character, (javascript should be '\w'
    `/, %, \, -, ?, &, =, !, #` character is permitted.
    `+` means one [] or more [].

and

`$0` : return whole matched <strike>only address part exclude "http" or "https"</strike> (javascript start with index 1).

Comment: `(?:` is no capturing group. This would not be captured by `$0`, `$0` will mean the whole expression here.

Comment: capturing group means assign result value memory assigning internally.   So it's slower than no-capturing group. So my saying is the same with your expression. and $0 thing, you are right in JAVA.

Comment: yep, you're right. I actually didn't see the tag. (even my answer, if you see edits) was initially Java oriented. BTW, I didn't downvote. Apologies.